# Formatting Integer Value Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am new in php and smarty formatting. I need to format an integer to take 5 places, for example to display 1 as 00001, 21 as 00021 and so on.

I tried string_format but instead of 00001 i was getting "    1". Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[string_format](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.string.format.tpl) in Smarty uses [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

So your code should look like this:

```
{$number|string_format:"%'.05d"}
```